# ADO NET Destination has failed to acquire the connection with the following error message: "Login failed for user

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql, ssis, azure-sql

Created a SSIS package, it is running fine when I run it on premise but when i try to execute it from sql server agent it gives me error for login failed for user, I am using SQL authentication to connect to the Azure database which are working fine on premise but erroring out on Job agent

This the Error I am getting:

```
Server Execute Package Utility Version 14.0.1000.169 for 
64-bit Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft. All rights reserved. Started: 10:59:46 AM Error: 2019-06-07 10:59:47.71 Code: 0xC0208452 
Source: Data Flow Task ADO NET Destination [2] Description: ADO NET Destination has failed to acquire the connection
 {F51F409E-2990-4C40-8DFF-0B078AF481D4} with the following error message: "Login failed for user 'SVCASQLDW'.".
 End Error Error: 2019-06-07 10:59:47.71 Code: 0xC0047017 
Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline Description: ADO NET Destination failed validation and returned error
 code 0xC0208452. End Error Error: 2019-06-07 10:59:47.71 Code: 0xC004700C 
Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline Description: One or more component failed validation. End Error Error: 2019-06-07 10:59:47.71 
Code: 0xC0024107 Source: Data Flow Task Description: 
There were errors during task validation. End Error DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE 
  (1). Started: 10:59:46 AM Finished: 10:59:47
 AM Elapsed: 0.875 seconds. The 
  package execution failed. The step failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that your connection string has password for your SQL Login or add configuration file for SSIS.